# how to get input from the user to specify the trip destination from dataset in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

A sample of the dataset:

```
Flights ID   To         From    
  90     Chicago      Macon     
  90     Chicago      Flora     
  90     Chicago      Highland  
  90     Flora        Macon    
  90     Highland     Macon
```

how to get input from the user to specify the trip destination from dataset?

```
FromData = [Chicago, Flora, Highland ]
ToData = [Macon, Highland, Flora]

print('Please Enter the where From:')
print('Please Enter the where To for which you would like to see the Statistics:')
```

Comment: using [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)?....

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** to work with dataset.

```
# sample data, no idea what file format
flight_id_data = [90,90,90,90,90]
from_data = ['Macon','Flora','Highland','Macon','Macon']
to_data = ['Chicago','Chicago','Chicago','Flora','Highland']

stats = {}
for f,t,i in zip(from_data,to_data,flight_id_data):
    if f not in stats:
        stats[f] = [(t,i)]
    else:
        stats[f].append((t,i))

from_opt= ['Macon' ,'Highland','Flora']
to_opt= ['Chicago', 'Flora', 'Highland']

print('From:')
for opt in enumerate(from_opt):
    print(opt)
fromm = input('Please enter #: ')

print('To:')
for opt in enumerate(to_opt):
    print(opt)
to = input('Please enter #: ')

f = from_opt[int(fromm)]  # cleanup input
t = to_opt[int(to)]
flights = 0
flight_id = None

if t in stats[f][0]:  # lookup flight
    flights += 1
    flight_id = stats[f][0][1]

print("From: %s -> To: %s = %s flight(s). ID: %s " % (f,t,flights, flight_id))
```